# Calling multiple callbacks with Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using an utility class that I wrote which shows an alert dialog with various actions. Per each action, I can utilize the `onPressed` method. Previously I've been using it to simply close the alert dialog, such as:

`onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true)`

This works great, until I want to pass an additional callback to be fired before I trigger the `Navigator`. When I'm passing in a callback into this class, I'm trying something like:

```
onPressed: () {
  this.cancelCallback;
  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
},
```

Where `this.cancelCallback` is the `VoidCallback` passed into this widget class. However, this is apparently the wrong syntax and Flutter is just passing over that and going straight to the `Navigator` logic.

The basic reasoning here is I'd want to pass in any callback logic to be fired prior to a cancel/accept event happening in an alert dialog. I can't figure out how to pass in a callback and fire this `Navigator` callback at the same time.

Comment: You are not calling the `cancelCallback` function, maybe that's why it is not triggered? 
`onPressed: () {
  this.cancelCallback();
  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
},`

Comment: Wow, what a silly oversight on my part. You are correct. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Someone did that already, you can accept his answer. 
It's ok as long as your issue got resolved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for calling functions in flutter you should add () after function name
`function();` and not  `function;` in `js` ,
`()` indicates a call to the function.
**Without `()`**
you've got just a reference to the function, in dart it has different
so

```
onPressed: () {
  this.cancelCallback();
  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
},
```